# PHP vs Java for enterprise web applications

Tags: java, php, jakarta-ee, web-applications

Is it possible to write enterprise web applications in PHP as it is in Java (with Java EE stack of technologies)? I know just a bit of PHP and I've always seen it like a request-process-response programming/scripting language with no objects staying alive on the server (like `@Stateful` ejbs) after the script has finished its execution.

To put it in another way: can the same web application be implemented in Java and in PHP? Or is one of the two languages more powerful than the other?

Edit: let me clarify my question: I already know Java and have some experience in enterprise web applications. I want to know if PHP is equally powerful (in language structure, in today available frameworks, and so forth) to make the same complex applications that can be done in Java.

Comment: "Is it possible to write enterprise web applications in PHP as it is in Java?". Yes.

Comment: Just adding a comment as this comes fairly high on google. For web applications, take your pick, both can work well. Java perhaps has the edge if your requirements are more diverse. You can write your web app, smartphone app, desktop app and embeded POS app in java. Php is not widely used outside web applications (and perhaps as a general purpose scripting language)

Comment: just remember that facebook uses php

Comment: I don't know if it is of any help, but you can run PHP applications on Java EE servers by using Caucho Quercus, a PHP engine written in Java. Be cautious, it's PHP 5 only... http://quercus.caucho.com/

Answer (score 11):

Not more powerful in the sense that you could write something in Java that would be impossible to replicate in PHP. I'm not familiar with PHP, but there's most likely similar frameworks and libraries that have been created for PHP that exist already in Java (such as an ORM framework like JPA).

Stateful EJBs aren't that special (and not that common either). You can readily store information in the session whether you're using Java or PHP.

This isn't really a suitable question for SO either, since programming languages are different and frameworks are different and you'll never find the "best" something, because that doesn't really exist.

Solution: learn both.

Comment: Well, I'm trying to understand if it could be worth learning PHP too, but if Wordpress-like or e-commerce websites is the maximum complexity that can be achieved with PHP, I'm not interested into it.

Comment: Plenty of large sites have been implemented in PHP. It's not about the language, it's about the programmer. What makes you think you'll be able to learn Java well enough to create something "more complex".

Comment: I already know Java and I'm using it in enterprise applications. I know that PHP is well widespread too, I want to understand how much is it powerful today compared to the full Java enterprise stack (maybe this wasn't very clear in my question). Can you provide some examples of those large sites that I can look at?

Comment: I hope you know Java better than you know how to use search engines. But I'll give you the first site for free: http://facebook.com

Comment: +1 for avoiding the flame-war with "learn both". Good advice!